# Total Trigger time in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a question regarding the "Triggers Total runtime" as mentioned in the link:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas

Triggers total runtime  1 hr / day  3 hr / day  6 hr / day

What is this limit referring to?

Comment: There are three types of Google accounts listed at the top of that table, "Consumer", ["Google Apps for Domain"](https://domains.google/), and "Google Apps for [Biz](https://apps.google.com/intx/en_ca/partner/recommended/)/[Edu](https://www.google.com/work/apps/education/)/[Gov](https://www.google.com/work/apps/government)".

Answer (score 2):

To build on what @Mogsdad stated about the various account types, this is the cumulative total time that all scripts called through [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) can run for.

As an example, you have a script that triggered `onOpen()` for a spreadsheet and the script takes 1 minute to run.  This would mean the spreadsheet owned by a Consumer (gmail.com) account, would execute the script 60 times (assuming no other scripts associated with the account ran) before the quota for the day is reached.